# Key Lookup using columns outside of the index in SQL Query

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-execution-plan, query-tuning

I have a query as follows

```
SELECT ActivityId,
       AnotherId,
       PersonId,
       StartTime AS MyAlias
FROM   Activity
WHERE  DeletedStatus='Active' AND
       StartTime>='2018-02-01'AND StartTime<='2018-02-08'
```

The execution plan being used is here

[Execution Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJiWUWvOf)

Index1 is defined as:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX Index1 ON Activity
(
    StartTime
)
```

Index 2 is defined as:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX Index2 ON Activity
(
     EndTime
     StartTime
)
```

The optimiser is using an index seek on Index1 and is then using a key lookup because ActivityId,AnotherId,PersonId, are in the `SELECT` list but not in the index. This makes sense to me.

However, the following things puzzle me:

- Why is the optimiser able to use Index1 to do an index seek when DeletedStatus is not in the index but is in the `WHERE` clause?
- Why does the output list in Index1 include EndTime when that column is not present in Index1?
- How is Index2 being used to output ActivityId,AnotherId,PersonId when none of those columns are in Index2?

Apologies, I have pseudo-anonymised the plan and the query so I hope I have done it correctly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the optimiser able to use Index1 to do an index seek when
>   DeletedStatus is not in the index but is in the WHERE clause?

The `WHERE` clause also includes `StartDate` so a seek can be performed using the provided `StartDate` values followed by a range scan. The key lookup includes the 'Active' predicate to filter the rows per the `WHERE` clause since that column is not included in the index.

> Why does the output list in Index1 include EndTime when that column is
>   not present in Index1?

All non-clustered indexes implicitly include the clustered index key as the row locator, similarly to explicitly included columns.

> How is Index2 being used to output ActivityId,AnotherId,PersonId when
>   none of those columns are in Index2?

The clustered index leaf nodes are the actual data rows so all columns are available.